# Removing non-allowed objects from a list in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary containing actors as keys and list of movie titles as values. Example:

```
{'Pacino, Al' : ['Scarface', 'Godfather', 'Heat', ...]}
```

I then have a function that take a dictionary with movie titles as keys and genres as values as an argument:

```
def is_movie(genre_dict, title):
    disallowed_genres = ["Reality-TV", "News", "Talk-Show",
                     "Game-Show", "Lifestyle", "Commercial",
                     "Documentary", "Music", "Biography"]
    if title in genre_dict and not "(TV)" in title:
        any_disallowed = False
        for genre in genre_dict[title]:
            any_disallowed = (any_disallowed or (genre in disallowed_genres))
        return not any_disallowed
    else:
        return False
```

I want to use that function to delete every movie in the list of movie titels in the original dicstionary.

I have tried to do the following:

```
def filter_actor_dictionary(actor_dict, genre_dict):
    temp_dict=actor_dict.copy() #Creates a copy of actor_dict
    for item in actor_dict.iteritems():
        if not is_movie(genre_dict, item):
           del temp_dict[item]
    return temp_dict
```

This give me "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'"

Edit:
The genre dictionary could be {'Heat' : 'Drama', 'Time is Illmatic' : 'Documentary'}, where all movie titles in the list corresponding to the actor which is listed as a non-allowed genre should be removed from my original dictionary.

Comment: what do you think item is?

Comment: After reading Padraics answer I understand that the item is the key and value set. I do however still get the same error after trying to access my element by typing del temp_dict[item[0]]

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: The expected output is a copy of the actor dictionary, but in the list of moives (which corresponds to the actor; key) should not contain movies of disallowed genres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your example `item` would be `[('Pacino, Al', ['Scarface', 'Godfather', 'Heat'])]` so `temp_dict[item]` is trying delete using the list as the key like below:

```
temp_dict[[('Pacino, Al', ['Scarface', 'Godfather', 'Heat'])]]
```

Use  `del temp_dict[item[0]]` to access the key or just iterate over `actor_dict` to access just the keys and use `temp_dict[item]`.

Using `is_movie` as required:

```
def filter_actor_dictionary(actor_dict ,genre_dict):
    temp_dict = actor_dict.copy()  #Creates a copy of actor_dict
    for key, val in actor_dict.iteritems():
        for title in val:
            if is_movie(genre_dict,title):
                temp_dict[key].remove(title)
    return temp_dict
```

There are parts of `is_movie` and `genre_dict` that are incorrect, it should be more like the following:

```
# need to store in a list or for genre in genre_dict[title] will be iterating over individual characters
genre_dict = {'Heat': ['Drama',"Talk-Show"], 'Time is Illmatic': ['Documentary']}

def is_movie(genre_dict, title):
    disallowed_genres = ["Reality-TV", "Drama","News", "Talk-Show",
                     "Game-Show", "Lifestyle", "Commercial",
                     "Documentary", "Music", "Biography"]
    if title in genre_dict and not "(TV)" in title:
        for genre in genre_dict[title]:
            # should return True if any genre is in disallowed_genres
            if genre in disallowed_genres:
                return True
    return False
```

The code could be written more concisely using any:

```
def is_movie(genre_dict, title):
    disallowed_genres = ["Reality-TV", "Drama","News", "Talk-Show",
                     "Game-Show", "Lifestyle", "Commercial",
                     "Documentary", "Music", "Biography"]
    if title in genre_dict and not "(TV)" in title:
            return any(genre in disallowed_genres for genre in genre_dict[title])
    return False
```

Comment: I have tried to change that, but still get the same TypeError.

Comment: why are you using iteritems, where are you using the values? I edited my answer

Comment: Sorry for being such a novice. I have tried to change the code, with the results that the returned dictionary is now empty. Is this because the key and the list of values are deleted if one object in the list is disallowed? I only want to remove the disallowed object and remain the rest of the objects in the list.

Comment: yes, when you remove  key you remove the key/value pairing. You need to reassign the key to the new value or if it is a list do `dict[key].remove(some_item)`

Comment: I am ashamed of asking, but is the key 'item' in my axample? And what should 'some_item' be assigned as? Should the line after 'if not is_movie' be: temp_dict[item].remove(item)?

Comment: `some_item` is the one of the values in the list you want to remove

Comment: I added a working function that should do what you want, I added Drama to the disallowed list just for the example

Comment: First of all, thanks for your patience. The fucntion you have provided works for me aswell, but I have to use the 'is_movie' function as it is presented. So I have to incorperate it into the 'filter_actor_dictionary' function. So that the filter function use the boolean expression from the is_movie. Sorry for causing all this trouble :)

Comment: so you cannot change the `is_movie` at all?

Comment: Unfortunately not. The is_movie function is provided by my assignment and cannot be changed. That is the reason I am trying to do this in a klunky way.

Comment: I hope whoever wrote it is not your only source of programming education!

Comment: Thus far google-searching and stackoverflow in particular is main source of programming education.
This function is the last problem in my assignment, so if I cannot get it to work I just have to handin the rest of it.
Thansk for your help anyway - at least i learned something!

Comment: there is one problem,in  your supplied code for genre in `genre_dict[title]` will iterate over the characters in the string unless `genre_dict's` values are actually list or tuples etc.. There are also issues with the logic

Answer (score 1):

I tried to understand *which film* Al himself would like to forget

```
In [1]: %colors LightBg

In [2]: d = {'Pacino, Al' : ['Scarface', 'Godfather', 'Heat',]}

In [3]: g = {'Scarface':1, 'Godfather':2, 'Heat':3}

In [4]: bad_g = [3,]

In [5]: def no_bad_genres(d,g,bad_g):                       
    for actor in d.keys():
        films = d[actor]
        for n, film in enumerate(films):
            if g[film] in bad_g:
                del films[n]
   ...:                 

In [6]: no_bad_genres(d,g,bad_g) ;  print d
{'Pacino, Al': ['Scarface', 'Godfather']}

In [7]:
```